# Why I cannot access a property inside my function?

Tags: javascript

Just need to access baseUrl in the post method on the code below.
What is the correct method of doing so?
And if you can explain to me why this does not work I would be thankful.

```
const API = {
  baseUrl: "http://my_api_address",

  post: (path, payload) => {
    let headers = {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    };

    let token = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
    if (token) {
      headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token;
    }

    alert(this); // shows undefined so I can't access this.baseUrl inside this function

    return fetch(this.baseUrl + path, {
      method: "POST",
      headers,
      body: JSON.stringify(payload)
   })
      .then(res => {
        return res.json().then(json => ({ json, res }));
      })
      .then(({ json, res }) => {
        if (!res.ok) {
          return Promise.reject(json);
        }

        return json;
      });
  }
};
```

As requested:

```
API.post("/account/resetpassword", data)
  .then(function(json) {
    UI.toggleModal("#modalId");
    UI.loader("hide");
    UI.alert(json.success, json.message);
  })
  .catch(function(json) {
    console.log(json);
  });
```

The code above works if I replace this.baseUrl with "http://my_api_address" so I don't think there is any other issue.

Comment: Don't use an arrow function for the post method. Just use `function(){}`. Arrow functions don't bind their own context but use the context from the position of definition.

Comment: Change `post: (path, payload) => {` to `post(path, payload) {` in order for it to be possible to access `this`

Answer (score 2):

It's because for `post:` you used an arrow function, which doesn't bind its own `this`, but rather uses the closest lexically defined one (if any).

Use `function() {...}` syntax instead.

Note that you didn't show the call to `API.post()`, so there could be other issues too

Comment: Aww, I didn't knew that. Thanks.